# How to loop-through content from Link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery Confirm 3.3.4 and I want to use the `$.fn.confirm` way as [described here](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/#jquery-fn).

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.4/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <a class="example2-1-1 btn btn-primary" data-title="Goto twitter?" href="http://twitter.com/craftpip">Goto twitter</a>
</p>

<script>
  $('.example2-1-1').confirm({
    content: "This will take you to my twitter <br> You can access the clicked element by <code>this.$target</code>",
  });
</script>
```

But I would like to put some content in the a-attribute to give it to the confirm-dialog.

For example:

```
<a class="example2-1-1" href="http://twitter.com/craftpip" myContent="some new content">Goto twitter</a>
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.example2-1-1').confirm({
  content: $(this).data("Content"),
  width: 'auto'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.4/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
<a class="example2-1-1" href="http://twitter.com/craftpip" data-Content="Wollen Sie wirklich zu Twitter?">Goto twitter</a>
```

Comment: Also works with `content: $(this).attr("data-Content")`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to your answer, you can use a more generic way and fetch the value of *any* attribute and not a `data-*` one:

```js
$('.example2-1-1').confirm({
  content: $(this).attr("data-Content"), // or any other attribute you have
  width: 'auto'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-confirm/3.3.4/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
<a class="example2-1-1" href="http://twitter.com/craftpip" data-Content="Wollen Sie wirklich zu Twitter?">Goto twitter</a>
```